# website shows blank when visiting from mobile

Tags: plugins

The website shows blank when visiting from mobile but it's totally fine when visiting from the desktop.
https://agribusiness.thefarmersmanual.com/
This is the website,
if you can share any idea to solve this site, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually a redirect problem:

```
This page isn’t workinga
gribusiness.thefarmersmanual.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

You will need to look into how the mobile version is set-up - responsive seems fine, but perhaps there is an addition JS redirect, which might not be needed.